# Create EF query extension with an Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, iqueryable

I want to write an Extension method of IQueryable to filter out some entities. This Method should have a parameter of type Expression<Func<T, int>> which is used to filter the entities.

This is my try and I don't know why this does not work. Any Ideas?

```
public static IQueryable<T> AddDefaultQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, int>> countryId, ApplicationDbContext db, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    if (claimsPrincipal.IsEppRole()) {
        var userCountryIds = db.UserCountry.Where(uc => uc.UserId == LoginUser.GetUserID(claimsPrincipal)).Select(uc => uc.CountryId);
        query = query.Where(q => userCountryIds.Contains(countryId.Compile()(q)));
    }
    return query;
}
```

The error is:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(a => a.Deleted == False)
> .Where(a => __userCountryIds_0.Contains(__Compile_1.Invoke(a)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently. The problem lays here:

> `Where(q => userCountryIds.Contains(countryId.Compile()(q)))`.

I learned that `Func` inside `Contains` inside `Where` is not exactly something that LINQ to SQL translator can handle. And as i noticed, *compiled* Expressions are not translated to SQL as well, they will be executed after the SQL is queried, which might cause a performance hit.

I'm guessing you have something like this as your expression

```
 Expression<Func<T, int>> expression = foo => foo.Id
```

Now if we create an expression like this:

```
//don't forget to put a constraint on T like 
//"where T : IHasId" or something like that
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildExpression<T>(ApplicationDbContext db, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    var userCountryIds = db.UserCountry
        //this one might also not be translated to SQL
        //because it uses function that is not supported by SQL
        .Where(uc => uc.UserId == LoginUser.GetUserID(claimsPrincipal))
        .Select(uc => uc.CountryId)
        .ToList();
    var isEppRole = claimsPrincipal.IsEppRole();
    return foo => !isEppRole || userCountryIds.Contains(foo.Id);
}
```

And then in your extension method

```
public IQueryable<T> AddDefaultQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, ApplicationDbContext db, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    var exp = BuildExpression<T>(db, claimsPrincipal);
    //no lambdas, nothing else except the expression itself
    return query.Where(exp);
}
```

This approach helped me, hopefully it will help you as well, or at least will point you in the right direction